# yld V.S yield on SCALA

Tags: scala

I am working in a project that use the following code:

```
case class R(f: Vector[String], s: Vector[String]) {
    def apply(name: String): String          = f(schema indexOf name)
    def apply(names: S): Vector[String] = names map (this apply _)
  }
      def processCSV(file: String)(yld: R => Unit): Unit = {
    val in = new Scanner(file)
    val s= in.next('\n').split(",").toVector
    while (in.hasNext) {
      val f = schema map (n => in.next(if (n == s.last) '\n' else ','))
      yld(R(f, s))
    }
  }

  def execOp(op: Operator)(yld: R => Unit): Unit = op match {
    case Scan(file, _, _, _)      => processCSV(file)(yld)}
```

Then My question is what is the meaning of yld? That is the same of yield? 
Exactly how works, someone can help me to understand how works this yld?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`yield` is a scala keyword used with [for-comprehensions](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/sequence-comprehensions.html).

`yld` in that code is VERY different: it is just the name that the author of the code gave one of the parameters to the functions `processCSV` and `execOp`. Any other name could have been given to those parameters: `fn`, `callback`, `cb`, etc. Nothing special there. Given the type `R => Unit`, it is just a function that takes `R` as input and return `Unit` (equivalent to `void` in java). Essentially, a callback where the work happens as side-effects.